# .htaccess Rewrite Rule 404 Error

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to get /game/game-name/ to redirect to /game.php?g=game-name

The code I am using in my .htaccess is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^game/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ game.php?g=$1
```

But when I go to /game/game-name/ I get a 404 Error. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your rule transform this url `/game/game-name/` into this `/game/game-name/game.php?g=game-name`

What you need to do is either this :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^game/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ /game.php?g=$1
```

Or this :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^game/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ game.php?g=$1
```

Comment: That still doesn't work. It really has me stumped. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Does you game name contain some character other than alphanumerics